# Store Data inside a Row List

Tags: roku, brightscript

I create My RowList Like below in XML.

```
id = "CRowList"
      translation = "[ 0, 100]" 
      numRows = "15" 
      itemSize = "[ 130, 70 ]" 
      rowItemSize = "[ [90, 70],[90,70],[90,70] ]" 
      rowItemSpacing="[[54,0],[18,0]]"
      rowLabelOffset="[[0,8]]"
      itemSpacing = "[ 0, 10 ]" 
      showRowCounter="[true]"
      showRowLabel = "[ true, true ]" 
      drawFocusFeedback = "false" 
      vertFocusAnimationStyle = "fixedFocusWrap" 
      rowFocusAnimationStyle = "fixedFocusWrap" />
```

and I fetch data in brs file like below. Here I used custom component which is a xmlreader. It behave to xml Data receive from server.
I tried to set like the below image and also I refer to a simple RowList example. It's here [RowList](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/scenegraph/list-and-grid-nodes/rowlist.md). Here I think I create a Content inside Content. Like Parent Content or Child Content. I set a Parent Content But, It behaves to display a title only like below image Row 1 and Row 2. and poster and label data comes from a Child Content. But I don't know how to set like this.

[image]

```
function init()

    ?"hello init() "

    m.CRowList = m.top.findNode("CRowList")
    m.readPosterGridTask = createObject("roSGNode", "XmlReader")
    m.readPosterGridTask.contenturi = "http://192.168.1.3/?file=AllChannel.xml"
    m.readPosterGridTask.observeField("content", "setpanels")
    m.readPosterGridTask.control = "RUN" 


    ?"hello rowlist"
    m.top.setFocus(true)

end function

function setpanels()

   ' ?"m.CRowList : " m.CRowList.content
    m.CRowList.content = m.readPosterGridTask.content 'here set bydefault to row title.
    i = 0
    while i < m.CRowList.content.getChildCount()
        ?"here displaya a data  : " m.CRowList.content.getChild(i).title
        ?"here hdposter url : "m.CRowList.content.getChild(i).hdposterurl
        i = i + 1
    end while
end function
```

In my xml data three item tag and every tag two attribute 1) Title and 2) hdposterurl.
But I unable to set here like the below image. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was literally just trying to use RowList yesterday and I ran into very similar problems.

I wanted to try and figure out what the appropriate way to use a RowList was, so I downloaded the [RowList example referenced by the Docs](https://github.com/rokudev/samples/tree/master/ux%20components/lists%20and%20grids/RowListExample) and ran it.

When it ran, I could see the section titles, but not the images in the Posters, despite these posters having valid uri's.

I believe there to be a bug with RowList itself and would recommend using a MarkupGrid instead. It offers much of the same functionality while being easier to use and less buggy.

Comment: I set a poster inside a RowList. First I only hdposterurl set on ContentNode and remove both title parent and child. and rowlistscene.xml use `rowlist.content = CreateObject("roSGNode", "RowListContent")`. I remove a rectangle because my image overrides with rectangle so pls remove rectangle and tried It's definitely working.